# Live Preview error when entry is disabled

Tags: live-preview

When the entry is disabled, the Live Preview only shows things which are outer of the main loop. This is a part of my code:

```
{% include "header.html" %}
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('flashback') %}
    <section id="intro" style="background-image: url('{{ entry.heroImage.first().getUrl() }}');">
        <h1>Flashback</h1>
    </section>
...
{% endfor %}
{% include 'footer.html' %}
```

The `header` and the `footer` are visible but the `section` and `headline` not.

Comment: Can you elaborate with a bit more template code?  "outer of the main loop" sounds like some things are displaying outside of a loop and things inside aren't? It'd be helpful to point out exactly what's happening in the code and what you're expecting to see.

Comment: Done. I hope this helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('flashback') %}
```

To:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('flashback').status(null) %}
```

The 2nd one will grab all entries regardless of their enabled/disabled status.

Comment: This works, but now the page is shown in the frontend even if it is disabled.

Comment: Is there any way to show the entry only in the Live Preview and not on the real page?

Comment: Not sure I'm following, but it sounds like you might need to wrap some of your template logic in a `if craft.request.isLivePreview()` conditional?

Comment: Yes this is what I'm searching for.